# Blackberry 10: Pushing and popping screens

Tags: blackberry-10

I know how to push a screen from my main screen by calling that main screen's `NavigationPane` object's `push(newScreen)` method.

Now what if I want to push another screen on top of the second one?? Do I have to get my `NavigationPane` to push it?? If so, how can I access my mainscreen's `NavigationPane` from my second screen(they are in separate files)?? I guess the same would apply for a third or fourth screen.

Also for popping screens, how do I get my second(or third) screen to pop itself?? This is assuming I have no back button, I would like to do this programmatically. Do I have to somehow get a reference to my mainscreen's `NavigationPane`?? And like in the first question, how can I do this??

**All examples I've seen on the matter were QML examples, I need to know how to do this in C++ (no QML at all).**

Any help at all (links, code snippets) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use a class for each page, where you pass the NavigationPane in the constructor. Take care not to extends the Page (it will not work), but instead use a factory class that will create the Page.
  This class could also contains all Q_INVOKABLE, etc, to communicate with the QML
- You can set the NavigationPane as the parent of the Page and cast it later with the method parent()
- You can set the NavigationPane as a property of the Page to retrieve it later.
- You can use a singleton or a static variable to stock the NavigationPane